# Remove spaces from a string but not new lines in lua

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I used `string.gsub(str, "%s+")` to remove spaces from a string but not remove new lines, example:

```lua
str = "string with\nnew line"
string.gsub(str, "%s+")
print(str)
```

and I'm expecting the output to be like:

```
stringwith
newline
```

what pattern should I use to get that result.

Comment: if you just want spaces then use `" "`

Comment: in lua patterns `%s` represent whitespace characters, which newline is too, so `string.gsub(str, "[ ]+", "")` should do what you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you want to match any whitespace matched with `%s` but exclude a newline char from the pattern.

You can use a reverse `%S` pattern (that matches any non-whitespace char) in a negated character set, `[^...]`, and add a `\n` there:

```lua
local str = "string with\nnew line"
str = string.gsub(str, "[^%S\n]+", "")
print(str)
```

See an [online Lua demo](https://ideone.com/mKwbZG) yielding

```lua
stringwith
newline
```

Comment: that's what I was looking for, removing more than one space and not remove a new line.

Answer (score 2):

`"%s"` matches any whitespace character. if you want to match a space use `" "`. If you want to define a specific number of spaces either explicitly write them down `"     "` or use `string.rep(" ", 5)`